# Git Commit changes not reflected in current state

Tags: git

I have made some changes in a file but the changes are not reflected when I checked out the latest state of repository.

My file is .project

output of commits in that file
Command `git log --all --oneline -- .project`
Output:

ba1cf9e manifest update
cc7a9ab contact impl
483f298 dd

output of git show

Command: `git show ba1cf9e -- .project`
Output:

```html
commit ba1cf9ecb3e5bfd96e77eaf99a5f76e454dbade0
Author: XXXX <XXXXX@XXXX.com>
Date:   Tue Mar 20 22:38:22 2018 +0530

    manifest update

diff --git a/contactApi/.project b/contactApi/.project
index 1b6d8a3..51e5d92 100644
--- a/contactApi/.project
+++ b/contactApi/.project
@@ -1,12 +1,28 @@
+<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <projectDescription>
-  <name>contactApi</name>
-  <buildSpec>
-    <buildCommand>
-      <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
-    </buildCommand>
-  </buildSpec>
-  <natures>
-    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
-  </natures>
-  <linkedResources> </linkedResources>
-</projectDescription>
\ No newline at end of file
+       <name>contactApi</name>
+       <comment></comment>
+       <projects>
+       </projects>
+       <buildSpec>
+               <buildCommand>
+                       <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
+                       <arguments>
+                       </arguments>
+               </buildCommand>
+               <buildCommand>
+                       <name>org.eclipse.pde.ManifestBuilder</name>
+                       <arguments>
+                       </arguments>
+               </buildCommand>
+               <buildCommand>
+                       <name>org.eclipse.pde.SchemaBuilder</name>
+                       <arguments>
+                       </arguments>
+               </buildCommand>
+       </buildSpec>
+       <natures>
+               <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
+               <nature>org.eclipse.pde.PluginNature</nature>
+       </natures>
+</projectDescription>
```

now the lastet state of file is
Command `vim .project`
Output:

```html
<projectDescription>
  <name>contactApi</name>
  <buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
      <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
    </buildCommand>
  </buildSpec>
  <natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
  </natures>
  <linkedResources> </linkedResources>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: Are there any uncommitted changes to the file right now?

Comment: what is the output of `git status .project` ?

Comment: @ElpieKay Everything is committed .

Comment: @LeGEC output of git status  is # On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: @user2839878 Have you run `git update-index --assume-unchanged/--skip-worktree -- .project`? What does `git ls-files -v -- .project` print?

Comment: @ElpieKay output of git ls-files -v -- .project is : 
H .project

Comment: Why are you doing `git log --all --oneline -- .project`?  The `—all` is potentially confusing.  You’ve then used the commit ID in `git show`.  Instead, what’s the output of `git show HEAD — .project`?